# Shutdown after certain time since start-up

Tags: linux, boot, shutdown, automation

I would like to shutdown the computer after it was running for e.g. 30 minutes.

I'm on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi) and I tried to put in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
shutdown -h 30
exit 0
```

but it doesn't work. What is more is that I have auto-login enabled but it stops working now (it shows the X login prompt) suggesting that the `rc.local` might not have finished correctly(?).

Please, can anyone help my further?

Comment: What do you find unpalatable in the solution below?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Nothing really, I was just hoping it would explain why the procedure with `rc.local` doesn't work. But in any case, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this line

```
@reboot /path/to/file
```

in sudo's `crontab` (`sudo crontab -e`). `file` is an executable file with content

```
#!/bin/bash

at -f /path/to/anotherfile now + 30 minutes
```

and eventually, `anotherfile` is also an executable file with content

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

This is of course brutal, you may wish to introduce some variations to be more lenient toward the sluggishness of your users, for instance you may use

```
/sbin/shutdown -h  +1 I am not feeling well today, I quit (in 1 minute).
```

Comment: This works! But wondering why could not we just put the shutdown command in crontab?

Comment: @vincentmathew Because crontab has no way to know when 30 minutes after boot have expired, it only knows about exact times.